# Finger or hand exercises while away from your instrument

Tags: electric-guitar, exercises

I mainly play electric guitar and would like to know what finger or hand exercises can people do while they are on holiday (vacation), at the office or even away from their instrument(s) for a longer period of time.

Answer (score -1):

If you are scared about practice, you could buy something like the Jamstik.

Comment: Enlightening us further with a description should result in some upvotes.

Comment: As this answer is written, it suggests a monetary purchase is a substitute for practice.

Comment: @YeDawg With my current income level and amount of free time, I **wish** that were true!